# Accessing global variable from within Switch statement

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a property called `total` which is an `NSDecimalNumber`. In my switch statement I'm trying to do some simple addition and subtraction on the number but I keep getting an '`unrecognized selector sent to instance`' error. Here is the code:

```
switch (t) {
case 0:
{
    if (_zero == YES)
    {
        _total = [_total decimalNumberBySubtracting:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"4.5"]];
        i = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:7];
        i.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        NSDecimalNumber *fourpointfive = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDecimal:[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.5] decimalValue]];
        _total = [_total decimalNumberByAdding:fourpointfive];
        i = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:7];
        i.hidden = NO;
    }
    break;
```

In the same method, just before the switch statement I initialize it:

```
_total = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDecimal:[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0] decimalValue]];
```

And in my @interface:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDecimalNumber *total;
```

Update:

Changed the initialization to:

```
_total = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"0"];
```

but it's still crashing. Also removed other references to `decimalValue`.

This is the error message I get:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber decimalNumberByAdding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: Can you show us the original initialisation of _total. If you haven't initialised it.. there's your problem

Comment: @JamesWebster added the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. I was saving my `NSDecimalNumber` to `NSUserDefaults`. NSDecimalNumber's saved to defaults are converted to `NSNumber` and returned as `NSNumber` when fetched again. I got the `floatValue` back from the defaults and converted that back to a `NSDecimalNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

on iOS NSNumber's decimalValue returns an NSDecimal, not NSDecimalNumber.

Comment: I changed that but I'm still getting the error. It crashes on the decimalNumberByAdding line.

Comment: I just compiled and ran your code fine.  You may want to post the crash log.

Comment: I just added the error message from the console in the question.

Comment: So, the problem is that you're calling decimalNumberByAdding on NSNumber.

Comment: I just found that actually. It was stored in my NSUserDefaults. Cleared those and removed all NSNumber references though and it's still crashing. Should this work:     NSDecimalNumber *n = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInt:0];
    [defaults setObject:n forKey:@"totalBurns"];

Comment: I think I've found the problem. When saving NSDecimalNumber to defaults I think it is auto converted to NSNumber! Do you know if that's correct?

Comment: Ok, problem solved. NSDecimalNumber's saved to defaults are converted to NSNumber and returned as NSNumber when fetched again. I got the floatValue back from the defaults and converted that back to a NSDecimalNumber. Thanks for your help.